# Can I browse the Safari history of my Ipad on my mac?

Tags: macos, ios, ipad, icloud, safari

My mac and my iPod share a common iCloud account. Is it possible to browse on my mac the history of Safari *on my iPad*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is currently not possible. Your browsing history is not shared over iCloud and can't be viewed on your Mac.

Answer (score 0):

No, instead use Google Chrome and synchronize history witch currently or previously open tabs with Windows, Mac, Android, iPad etc.